# computing sum of pandas dataframes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have two dataframes that I want to add bin-wise.  That is, given

```
dfc1 = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(range(10),np.zeros(10))), columns=['bin', 'count'])
dfc2 = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(range(0,10,2), np.ones(5))), columns=['bin', 'count'])
```

which gives me this

dfc1:

```
       bin  count
0        0      0
1        1      0
2        2      0
3        3      0
4        4      0
5        5      0
6        6      0
7        7      0
8        8      0
9        9      0
```

dfc2:

```
       bin  count
0        0      1
1        2      1
2        4      1
3        6      1
4        8      1
```

I want to generate this:

```
       bin  count
0        0      1
1        1      0
2        2      1
3        3      0
4        4      1
5        5      0
6        6      1
7        7      0
8        8      1
9        9      0
```

where I've added the count columns where the bin columns matched.

In fact, it turns out that I only ever add 1 (that is, count in dfc2 is always 1). So an alternate version of the question is "given an array of bin values (dfc2.bin), how can I add one to each of their corresponding count values in dfc1?"

My only solution thus far feels grossly inefficient (and slightly unreadable in the end), doing an outer joint between the two bin columns, thus creating a third dataframe on which I do a computation and then project out the unneeded column.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

First set `bin` to be index in both dataframes, then you can use `add`, fillvalue is needed to point that zero shall be used if bin is missing in dataframe:

```
dfc1 = dfc1.set_index('bin')
dfc2 = dfc2.set_index('bin')
result = pd.DataFrame.add(dfc1, dfc2, fill_value=0)
```

Pandas automatically sums up rows with equal index.

By the way, if you need to perform such operation frequently, I strongly recommend using [numpy.bincount](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html), which allows even repeating the bin index inside one dataframe

Comment: As like in my answer, **add** and **combineAdd** will be very efficient in this case, +1

Comment: Thanks for the note about numpy.bincount, good suggestion. I could, indeed, modify my code slightly so that I have just a set of numpy arrays (e.g., array([0,2,4,6,8]) for dfc2). I'll have to time it to see whether building an array of arrays, flattening, and calling bincount is better or worse than passing through dataframes.

Comment: Addendum: The code is so much simpler (and sufficiently efficient) using numpy.bincount that it wins without finishing the time comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Since the dfc1 index is the same as your "bin" value, you could simply do the following:

```
dfc1.iloc[dfc2.bin].cnt += 1
```

Notice that I renamed your "count" column to "cnt" since count is a pandas builtin, which can cause confusion and errors!

Comment: Although it achieves exactly what OP's after, but this solution isn't quite efficient.

Comment: What is inefficient about it?

Comment: your approach is trying to modify an existing dataframe, it's like manipulating a list under a for loop... you get the idea. And try to run a **%timeit**, I bet it's much slower than other approaches, which OP clearly wants efficiency.

Comment: don't get me wrong, I think your approach is the most sensible answer given that yours doesnt require indexing on **bin**, however OP is not asking **how to** but **how to improve**.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative of @Alleo's answer, you can use method `combineAdd` to simply add 2 dataframes together and `set_index` at the same time, provided that their indexes will be matched by **bin**:

```
dfc1.set_index('bin').combineAdd(dfc2.set_index('bin')).reset_index()

   bin  count
0    0      1
1    1      0
2    2      1
3    3      0
4    4      1
5    5      0
6    6      1
7    7      0
8    8      1
9    9      0
```